# ¿Cómo hago en oracle un select que me devuelva los trigers que realizan un autoincremental?

Tags: mysql, oracle

He usado una herramienta para trasladar una base de datos de Oracle a  Mysql, y me fallado al enviar los autoincrementales. NEcesito realizar una consulta que me devuelva estos disparadores.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit] para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [help/on-topic]. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La información que requieres se encuentra en las siguientes tablas en Oracle:

```
user_trigger_cols 
user_dependencies 
user_tab_cols
```

Una vez obtenidos los Triggers debes realizar una metaconsulta para realizar la migración a Mysql y usar Prepared Statment para ejecutarla.

```
set @qry = 'la-consulta'
prepare stmt from @qry;
execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Ejemplo de la consulta que creo que pretendes obtener, comprende que realizo la consulta pensando que estás en Oracle y que más tarde copiarás el resultado para ser ejecutado en Mysql:

```
/*
-Suponiendo que las tablas en Mysql ya se han creado y necesitas añadir una clave autonumérica.
-Cada Fila devuelta corresponderá a un Prepared Statment
*/


select 'ALTER TABLE ' ||  t.table_name,   
   ' change ' ||   c.COLUMN_NAME,
   c.COLUMN_NAME,
   (select DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns where table_name=t.table_name  
    and column_name=c.COLUMN_NAME) as "tipoDato",
             '(' ||

   (select DATA_PRECISION from user_tab_columns where table_name=t.table_name  
             and column_name=c.COLUMN_NAME)
             || ') NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT;' 
             as "data precision",             
             'select @ai :=  (SELECT MAX(' || c.COLUMN_NAME || ')+1 FROM ' || t.table_name||' ) ;',
             'set @qry = concat(' || CHR(39) || 'alter table '|| t.table_name||' auto_increment=' || CHR(39) || ',@ai);
             prepare stmt from @qry;execute stmt;DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;'--El Prepared Statment
  from user_trigger_cols t, user_dependencies d, user_tab_cols c
where d.name = t.trigger_name
   and t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
   and t.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME
   and d.referenced_type = 'SEQUENCE'
   AND d.REFERENCED_OWNER = 'OWNER';--Cambie aquí el owner
```

Aún así tendrás que revisar si la migración se ha hecho correctamente y algunas claves las tendrás que migrar a mano.

**Revisa el comentario que te dejaron para realizar una pregunta correctamente y que toda la comunidad te pueda ayudar.**